# How to use array in Verilog actually?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I found that in`Verilog`, the `array` can only be declared in `reg`.
And I found that it seems like if can only work in `for loop` such as

```
integer i;
reg [3:0] a [0:3];
for (i=0; i<5; i=i+1)
a[i] <= i;
```

what if I want to run in `case`?

```
module testrun(

input [7:0] b,
input clk, rst,
output reg [7:0] c , d, f

);

reg state = 0;
reg [7:0] a = 5;

reg [7:0] e [0:128];

integer i = 0;
//reg [7:0] command = 0;

always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
begin
    if (rst)
    begin
        c<=0;
        d<=0;
    end


else begin
    if (state == 0)
    begin
        case (i)
        i: begin
                e[i] <= a + 1;
                f <= a + 1;
                c <= e[i];
                i <= i + 1;
                a <= a + 1;

                state <= 1;
            end
        endcase
    end

    if (state == 1)
    begin
        d <= b + b;
        state <= 0;
    end
end
end

endmodule
```

above is the code I test to see if the value of `a + 1` can write into `e[i]`, then write it into `output c` in the next clock.
However, what I get is the `output c` is zero all the way. but it shows the expected result of `output d`. Means `case` actually working just that `array` is not working.
What is the problem? Or this can only be sone in SystemVerilog?
By the way, I use `University Program VWF` to monitor the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then write it into output c in the next clock.

No you don't.
`e[i]` does not receive that value until the next clock cycle. Thus `c <= e[i];` gets the old value of e[..]. 
 But by the next clock cycle you have changed  `i`, you incremented it: `i <= i + 1;` so `c` still does not get that value of `e[i]`